# How to configure Phoenix to serve different apps based on different IPs

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to know how to make Phoenix serve different apps that run on the same server when you have different IPs pointing to that same server.

For example, you have AppA and appB Phoenix apps running on the same server and same port (80) and if the request comes from IP X.X.X.X you'll serve appA. If the request comes from IP Y.Y.Y.Y you'll serve appB.
I tried a simple experience and I cannot have two apps running on the same port (if I don't configure anything else).
I found the Plug.Adapters.Cowboy that I think could be used for this purpose. As per documentation there is an option that allow us to define the IP to bind the server to, for example:

Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.http MyPlug, [], ip: {188, 250, 167, 106}

My questions are:

1) where to place this (in which file/order)? I suppose it should be the first Plug inside `endpoint.ex` file...

2) What's the Plug name (MyPlug) that should be used?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be to use Nginx to achieve this. For example you could set up your two different phoenix apps on different ports e.g.

```
#App 1
config :appname, AppName.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 8888],
  url: [host: "host"],
  server: true,
  root: ".",
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/manifest.json"

#App 2
config :appname, AppName.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 8889],
  url: [host: "host"],
  server: true,
  root: ".",
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/manifest.json"
```

Then you could simply use the [Http_access_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html) to do something like this:

```
server {
    if ($remote_addr = 1.2.3.4) {
        rewrite ^ http://www.website.com/noscrape.htm;
    }
   ...
}
```

This [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/380642/nginx-how-to-redirect-users-with-certain-ip-to-special-page) here goes into more detail and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0), shows how to use nginx to redirect to different ports.

Comment: Thank you. This is a solution, indeed. Nevertheless I would like to get a solution without nginx and inside the Phoenix Framework.

Comment: @PauloJaneiro fair enough - so you are looking at trying to do this through phoenix alone?

Comment: Yes. I think that if we have a native solution we should favor it. I just edited my question with a supposition